# Why can't I remove data from Firebase Database and Storage?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am using the code below for uploading photos and data to firebase.

```
  static func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String, videoUrl: String? = nil, ratio: CGFloat, caption: String, Location: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let newPostId = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId().key
    let newPostReference = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(newPostId)

    guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER else {
        return
    }

    let currentUserId = currentUser.uid

    let words = caption.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    for var word in words {
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {
            word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
            let newHashTagRef = Api.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
            newHashTagRef.updateChildValues([newPostId: true])
        }
    }

    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    var dict = ["uid": currentUserId ,"photoUrl": photoUrl, "caption": caption, "Location": Location, "likeCount": 0, "ratio": ratio, "timestamp": timestamp] as [String : Any]
    if let videoUrl = videoUrl {
        dict["videoUrl"] = videoUrl
    }

    newPostReference.setValue(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
        (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        Api.Feed.REF_FEED.child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).child(newPostId)
            .setValue(["timestamp": timestamp])
        Api.Follow.REF_FOLLOWERS.child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in
            let arraySnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            arraySnapshot.forEach({ (child) in
                print(child.key)
                Api.Feed.REF_FEED.child(child.key).child(newPostId)
                    .setValue(["timestamp": timestamp])
                let newNotificationId = Api.Notification.REF_NOTIFICATION.child(child.key).childByAutoId().key
                let newNotificationReference = Api.Notification.REF_NOTIFICATION.child(child.key).child(newNotificationId)
                newNotificationReference.setValue(["from": Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid, "type": "feed", "objectId": newPostId, "timestamp": timestamp])
            })
        })
        let myPostRef = Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(currentUserId).child(newPostId)
        myPostRef.setValue(["timestamp": timestamp], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        })
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
        onSuccess()
    })
}
```

I use a button and the code below for deleting a photo and to remove the data from Firebase.

```
 @IBAction func DeletePost(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER else  {
        return
    }

    let newPostId = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId().key
    let currentUserId = currentUser.uid   
    let newPostReference = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(newPostId)

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Post", message: "Are You Sure ?", preferredStyle: .alert);

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil));

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) {(action) in 
        Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(currentUserId).child(newPostId).removeValue()

  { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
        print("error")
        return
        }
        print("Posts Deleted")
        }

     };
       alert.addAction(okAction);

     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);

      }
```

The project runs fine but when I touch the button to delete a post, nothing happens!

> Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(currentUserId).child(newPostId).removeValue()

This code doesn't have any problems and must working fine so where is the problem?

[image: Xcode simulator]

Comment: You delete data by calling `removeValue` on a `FIRDatabaseReference` to that data. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#delete_data

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
var photoRef = DatabaseReference()
```

Put in ViewDidLoad :

```
photoRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
```

You must have stored the The_Unique_id somewhere.And you will be having the url of the image that you want to delete.

Put on your button click:  `statusRef.child("The_Unique_id").child("Pass_Your_imageUrl_Here").removeValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(currentUserId).removeValue()
Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(newPostId).removeValue()
```